# Animation in Visual 2D Arrays

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I'm currently making a Pacman ghost with visual 2D arrays. I want the ghost to move like this: [image]

I think I would use CSS transitions, but I'm not sure how! If there's a way to do it in javascript, that would be just as helpful. Here is my code:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
    <title>Visualizing 2D arrays</title>
    <style>
        #stage {
            position:relative;
        }

        .cell {
            position:absolute;
            width:30px;
            height:30px;
            border:1px solid black;
            background-color:black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="stage"></div>

    <script>
    // GRAB A REFERENCE TO THE STAGE
    var stage = document.querySelector("#stage");

    // THE 2D ARRAY THAT DEFINES THE PATTERN
    var pattern =   [
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0],
                [0,0,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,0,0],
                [0,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0],
                [0,0,3,3,2,2,1,1,3,3,2,2,1,1,0,0],
                [0,1,3,3,2,2,1,1,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,0],
                [0,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,0],
                [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
                [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],
                [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
            ];

    // THE SIZE OF EACH CELL
    var SIZE = 30;

    // THE SPACE BETWEEN EACH CELL
    var SPACE = 10;

    // DISPLAY THE ARRAY
    var ROWS = pattern.length;
   var COLS = pattern[0].length;

    // CREATE THE DIVS and POSITION THEM IN THE STAGE... BUT DON'T WORRY ABOUT COLORING THEM HERE!!!!
    for (var row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {

for (var col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {

    // CREATE A DIV HTML ELEMENT CALLED CELL
    var cell = document.createElement("div");

    // SET ITS CSS CLASS TO CELL
    cell.setAttribute("class", "cell");

    // GIVE EACH OF THE CREATED DIVS A UNIQUE ID
    // BASED ON THE ROW# AND COL#
    // EXAMPLE : <div id="c-1-2" class="cell"></div>
    // In this example, row = 1 and col = 2
    cell.setAttribute("id", "c-" + row + "-" + col);

    // ADD A CLICK HANDLER TO EACH OF THE INDIVIDUAL DIVS
    cell.addEventListener("click", cellClick, false);

    // ADD THE DIV HTML ELEMENT TO THE STAGE
    stage.appendChild(cell);

    // POSITION THE CELL IN THE CORRECT PLACE
    // WITH 10 PIXELS OF SPACE AROUND IT
    cell.style.top = row * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";
    cell.style.left = col * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";

}

    }

    colorizeDivs();

   function cellClick() {
// RIP APART THE DIV ID THAT WAS CLICKED ON
// WERE HIDING THE ROW AND COLUMN IN THE ID
// THE FORMAT OF THE ID IS "C-ROW#-COL#"
// EXAMPLE : <div id="c-1-2" class="cell"></div>
// In this example, row = 1 and col = 2
var zpos;

// THE "this" KEYWORD RETURNS THE HTML ELEMENT THAT WAS CLICKED ON
var thisid = this.id;

zpos = thisid.indexOf("-");
thisid = thisid.substr(zpos+1);

zpos = thisid.indexOf("-");
var thisRow = thisid.substr(0,zpos);
var thisCol = thisid.substr(zpos+1);

// now that we have the row and column for this div... change the array 
pattern[thisRow][thisCol] += 1;
if (pattern[thisRow][thisCol] > 7) {
    pattern[thisRow][thisCol] = 0;
}

colorizeDivs();
    }

    function colorizeDivs() {
for (var row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {

        var cell = document.querySelector("#c-" + row + "-" + col);

        if (pattern[row][col] === 0) {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        } else if (pattern[row][col] === 1) {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
        } else if (pattern[row][col] === 2) {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        } else if (pattern[row][col] === 3) {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        } else if(pattern[row][col] === 4) {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        } else if(pattern[row][col] === 5) {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else if(pattern[row][col] === 6) {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
        } else if(pattern[row][col] === 7) {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
        }
    }
}
}
    </script>       

        </body>

    </html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you would be able to use CSS transitions in this case. Transitions are typically applied to an entire HTML element, while you are attempting to selectively change certain colours of the ghost. I have created a solution to your problem in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Varn/bz4qzsae/2/). What this solution does is add another visual pattern representing the second frame of the ghost movement, as shown below:

```
var patterns = [
  [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ],
  [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  ]
];
```

The next important aspect for creating this animation is to create a render loop with the `requestAnimationFrame` function. This is simply used to run the `render` function as fast as possible,

```
var startTime = Date.now();
var SPEED = 5; // Runs 5 times per second

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render.bind(this));
  var elapsed = (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000;
  var index = Math.floor((elapsed * SPEED) % patterns.length);
  colorizeDivs(patterns[index]);
}

render();
```

So what the render function first does is calculate how long the animation has run for in seconds, which is also known as the `elapsed time`. This value can then be used to retrieve the appropriate `index` from the `patterns` defined above. This calculation simply applies the floor and modulo operation so that the index is always from the bound `0` to `patterns.length - 1`. After the index is retrieved, the current pattern is passed into the `colorizeDivs` function so the cells can be updated.